# Return 401 instead of redirect to login page when using JwtBearer authentication in Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

In Startup I have

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
```

and later

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Two questions

1. How can I set authorization to be enabled by default except to those controllers/actions that have [AllowAnonymous]?
2. How can I make the code return 401 instead of redirecting to Login page?

There are many questions and answers regarding this but they always seems to be about site with many authentication schemes, like both cookie and jwt. I have a pure jwt authenticated backend and only the token issuer endpoint will have anonymous access, everything else is authenticated and authorized.

Comment: This code never generates redirects. Do you also have AddIdentity or AddCookies in your startup?

Comment: @Tratcher I also have services.AddIdentity<User, Role>();. Is that adding some additional middleware?

Comment: Yes, that's adding Cookies and replacing your defaults. Why do you have Identity when you want all of your endpoints to use JWT? Start by switching the order.

Comment: MathiasR, did you fix this issue? I have the same now and can not fix it. Can you help me?

Comment: @Tratcher Thank you! that was my problem.

Comment: @Tratcher because Identity is needed for `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`, and I still need to validate / add users. I ended up finding some code to set custom response for cookies

Comment: Any solution? I'm facing same issue with Dot Net Core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to configure the **StatusCodePages** middleware to avoid the redirect.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you explain this more?