# Make Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute return 401, instead of redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an Angular application with .Net core 2.2 backend, and an external authentication provider. I wish to use Authorize attribute on receiving requests and either return the data on the method, or 401 if person is unatuhorized.

Currently it just redirects to whatever DefaultChallengeScheme is set to.

In `startup.cs`
I have tried removing DefaultChallengeScheme from `services.AddAuthentication()`, tried this codeblock:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.InvokeHandlersAfterFailure = false;
});
```

Attempted to also try `app.UseStatusCodePages()` as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708567/return-401-instead-of-redirect-to-login-page-when-using-jwtbearer-authentication).

My authentication setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = ExternalAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ExternalAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddExternalProvider(options =>
    {
        // ...
    });
```

Removing `options.DefaultChallengeScheme` override just uses vanilla login page routing, instead of redirecting to an external provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that I have been looking at the situation the wrong way. I need to have an internal `[Authorize]` handler either it being cookies or Jwt.

```
.AddExternalProvider(options =>
{
    // ...
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint /* could also be OnRedirectToLogin */ = context =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
})
```